# Get rid of "Restore pages" after killing Microsoft Edge (Chromium)

Tags: microsoft-edge

Whenever I shut my computer down, without closing all my programs manually, Microsoft Edge (Chromium) pop up with this the next time I launch it:

[image]

Any idea how I can get it to stop doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how I can get it to stop doing this?

Navigate to the following page: edge://settings/onStartup then select "Open a new tab". You can also just close Edge before you shutdown your computer.  Restoration of your session is a feature of Chromium/Chrome/Edge, by selecting "open a new tab", your session (open tabs) will be discarded when Edge is closed.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
While that may be a working solution, I don't want it to reopen up everything I had open when I turned off my machine last time. Sorry for not clarifying :)
I just want it to open a new tab without the "restore pages" thing bothering me until I click it off

Comment: Microsoft Edge shouldn't ask to restore your session if it's not configured to save your session.  If you close Edge before shutting your computer, that will close the session, and the next time you start Edge you won't be prompted to restore the session.

Comment: It's currently configured to open a blank new page. If you configure it to restore then it doesn't ask, it just opens all the previously opened ones