# Get rid of the "Restore pages" warning in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, session-restore

I am resurrecting [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1600365/156554), because I haven't found any conclusive answer or working resolution. This question was asked 1,5 year ago and the problem still exists.

Whenever you close your system without prior closing the Microsoft Edge, upon next launch you'll see the following warning:

[image]

This is very annoying. Is there any way to get rid of it or block this behavior?

Things I've tried so far:

1. I have disabled the *Startup boost* and the *Continue running background extensions and apps when Microsoft Edge is closed* options but this brought no help
2. The [provided answer](https://superuser.com/a/1600369/156554) is not an option. I don't want to have my "Startup" queue empty
3. The solution [suggested in here](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-close-restore-pages-pop-up-in-chrome/213168/3) is a total misunderstanding and absolutely not an option for me. Making *preferences* file (which Edge updates 5-10 times per each minute!) read-only is asking for a serious troubles
4. Solution [proposed in here](https://forum.uipath.com/t/how-to-close-restore-pages-pop-up-in-chrome/213168/5) is also not an option for me. I am using an office PC and I am not allowed to install any 3rd party plugins to Microsoft Edge, due to company policy

I recall that the first solution (disabling mentioned options) resolved this problem for me on Windows 10. But on Windows 11 it doesn't work anymore.

Is there anything else that I can try to fix this?

Comment: due to company policy  ......    on Windows 11 it doesn't work anymore.    ....  I have genuinely found it to be easiest (by far) to close Edge (and all other apps)  before shutting down or restarting. A little bit of up front effort pays me big dividends.  I, too, am running Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: (not an Edge user) You can close it by pressing Escape right? Maybe it is possible to write an AutoIt script (or something similar) that checks if that window is open and presses Escape to close it. Or you can do that manually like a caveman.

Comment: Is there no flag [edge://flags] option to disable this?

Comment: @JW0914 - The problem is the underline feature is from Chromium.  In order to get the prompt in question, it means Microsoft Edge wasn't properly closed.  Sadly, I suspect to get the functionality the author wants, will require an extension but that isn't possible.

Comment: @John I totally agree with you. Closing all apps with "x" before closing Windows 11 brings my to my Desktop to show me, if I have some things left (I put "notes to future self" in form of short-living links-URL shortcuts to my Desktop) or some mess in a trash. I'd consider (by you or someone else) to write an answer out of these comments that otherwise then using scripts or extensions this isn't solvable at all per current knowledge.

Comment: @Gantendo That's one of the ideas that is possible, but I'd like to avoid (for "clean solutions" reasons). Based on one of the cited answers I have come with an idea of a "watchdog" program that constantly monitors _preferences_ file of Edge and for `exited_cleanly` JSON flag inside and always changes it to `true` whenever it detects that it was switched to `false`. The stupidest thing is that they wrote an extra code that runs when Windows closes and that changes this flag to `false`, if Edge is still running. For what reasons? Only Microsoft knows...

Comment: @JW0914 To be honest, I consider all the flags (in Edge and in Chrome) as the solution last or none. Past has shown that the most important flags are very often descoped and deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @John I totally agree with you. ....   I'd consider (by you or someone
> else) to write an answer

I, too, am running Windows 11 Pro

I have genuinely found it to be easiest (by far) to close Edge (and all other apps) before shutting down or restarting. A little bit of up front effort pays me big dividends.

I have not found any other way either.

It takes me about 30 seconds to close apps before restarting or shutting down, so there is not a big penalty to this method.

Comment: @trejder This could also be automated via Task Scheduler by setting the trigger to be a shutdown event, which could gracefully close out edge before logging out.

Comment: @JW0914 Why don't you then craft another answer here, showing step-by-step how to achieve this? That could be another (even better?) answer to the currently accepted one.

Comment: @trejder I didn't really see it as another answer, more of a piggy-back on John's answer since it's the same thing, just automating it via a task. I can create an answer tomorrow morning, but didn't want to take away from John's idea.

Comment: @JW0914 It's completely up to you as a (potential) answer's author. I see your answer as different. It does not involve user interaction (is automatic) and it does require much more knowledge (for example, I have zero-to-none experience in using Task Scheduler in Windows). John's answer is good as long as you remember to not press "Power off" before closing Edge! :)

Comment: @trejder Configuring it as a task is a bit more complicated than I thought it would be, as every cli option I've tried to use to shutdown Edge performs a dirty close, resulting in a similar box when Edge is re-launched. If a command to cleanly close Edge exists, the task would be configured to use an Event with Log: `System`, Source: `User32`, and Event ID: `1074`. Reviewing the Chromium cli options for `msedge.exe` doesn't list a command to close `msedge.exe`, and `TaskKill`/PowerShell equivalent performs a dirty close.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for your time and the great investigation. That's why I said that a possible script would rather work after restart (or work all the time) and would clean the corresponding flag from _settings_ file. But, a much, much easier way is... to just hit _ESC_ key than mock around with scripts for such a trivial problem! :)

Comment: @trejder I came across [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/e10e1995-1bc9-4063-89d1-6ef1567a898f/issues-while-running-powershell-scripts-when-shutting-down-the-pc?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues) today and the fifth post will be of some interest to you _(I don't have the time to test this at the moment, but can later)_

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for being all the time on this topic. I think that even without testing this seems to be the right solution. However, I learnt myself to manually close Edge before closing the system (which is also very good for some "forgotten" downloads) so the problem does not exist anymore. And if I forget to close it that way then simple hit to Esc upon reopen solves the problem. I am not sure, if jiggling with extra shutdown scripts just to solve such a simple problem is a correct path after all! :) Thanks again.